# VSCode - how to make JSON file implement a TypeScript interface

Tags: json, typescript

Let's say I have a TypeScript interface like:

```js
interface Settings {
    id?: number
    tag: string
}
```

How can I enforce all `.json` files in some directory to follow these rules?

In case VS Code can't do that, any idea how can I validate the files in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Even if VSCode would think all those files are following the interface, when the app is running JS does not know about the interface and the wont be validated.

If you want to validate it at runtime, you have to validate it yourself.

Comment: Is there a command that can do it? Something like `tsc --noEmit`?

Comment: These files need to checked only during building, not in production.

Comment: I would archive this by creating a prebuild script, which validates these files. This might not be the best way but its the best way I currently can think of.